# How can I control in which of my desktops the browser called by selenium remote server will pop up?

Tags: linux, selenium, phpunit, selenium-rc, kde-plasma

I am running tests from phpunit using selenium. Since the tests take a couple of minutes proceed, I would like to switch to another desktop and do some tasks while the tests are running in the background.

However, since every test calls a new browser via selenium remote server, and a new test management window and a application window are started, these new windows do not appear in the desktop which I started the php tests from, but in my current desktop taking the focus away from the window I am working in.

How can I control that the browsers are always opens in the desktop that is in the background (where I start phpunit)? I am using Kubuntu i.e. the KDE Desktop.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a bit late, but for anyone reading this: When you launch your selenium RC server, you could try exporting to a specific display using the command:

```
export DISPLAY="somedisplay" && java -jar /path/to/selenium-server.jar
```

Using this, you could also export it to for instance an X virtual frame buffer (Xvfb), effectively running it in the background.